# How to convert a column with list to different rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website:- https://spfpharmacy.com/

I have successfully scraped this using selenium using the below code.

```
    test_list = []
    test_list = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    
        med_url = []
        for i in tqdm(test_list):
        driver.get(f'https://spfpharmacy.com/search/?drugName={i}')
        for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='rxrequired default']"):
            med_url.append(i.get_attribute("href"))
    
    data = []
    for i in tqdm(med_url):
        driver.get(i)
        time.sleep(1)
        
        try:
            med_name = []
            for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='brand_dose']//div[@class='product-name']"):
                med_name.append(i.text)
        except:
            med_name.append(None)
            
        try:
            manuf_name = []
            for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='brand_dose']//div//span[@class='manufactured-name']"):
                manuf_name.append(i.text)
        except:
            manuf_name.append(i.text)
            
        try:
            country = []
            for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='brand_dose']//div//span[@class='product-country']"):
                country.append(i.text)
        except:
            country.append(None)
            
        try:
            pres_req = []
            for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='brand_dose']//div//span[@class='product-prescription']"):
                pres_req.append(i.text)
        except:
            pres_req.append(None)
        
        str_price =  []
        try:
            for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='brand_dose']//div//span[@class='product-dose-text']"):
                for j in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,f"//div[@id='brand_dose']//div//select//option[@data-str='{i.text}']"):
                    str_price.append({i.text, j.text})
        except:
            str_price.append(None)
            
        data.append({
            'Medicine_name':med_name,
            'Manufacture_name':manuf_name,
            'Product_Counry':country,
            'Prescription_Required':pres_req,
            'Product_Details':str_price})
```

where test_list is a list of alphabets in uppercase which completes the URL like:-

https://spfpharmacy.com/search/?drugName=A  which gives the details of all the medicines with A.

After scraping the data I am getting results as shown below:-

[image: Output Head]

But I want to get the name of each medicine in a single row and all details associated with that medicine under different columns.

Something like this.
[image: Expected Output]

I tried using explode, and transform and also searched over the internet and stack overflow but was unable to convert this into the expected format.

Also, is there any other way of scraping data from this website like calling API directly and getting the requested data in the correct format?

Here's the code:-

```
df.head(5).to_dict(orient="list")
```

Output:-

```
{'Medicine_Name': ['Abacavir',
  'Abacavir - Lamivudine',
  'Abilify (Aripiprazole)',
  'Abilify Maintena Injection',
  'Abiraterone'],
 'Bran_Name_Choices': [['Ziagen 300mg'],
  ['Kivexa 600mg/300mg'],
  ['Abilify 2mg',
   'Abilify 5mg',
   'Abilify 10mg',
   'Abilify 15mg',
   'Abilify 20mg',
   'Abilify 30mg',
   'Abilify Maintena Injection 300mg',
   'Abilify Maintena Injection 400mg'],
  ['Abilify Maintena Injection 300mg', 'Abilify Maintena Injection 400mg'],
  ['Zytiga 250mg', 'Zytiga 500mg']],
 'Generic_Name_Choices': [['Abacavir 300mg'],
  ['Abacavir - Lamivudine 600mg/300mg'],
  ['Aripiprazole 2mg',
   'Aripiprazole 5mg',
   'Aripiprazole 10mg',
   'Aripiprazole 15mg',
   'Aripiprazole 20mg',
   'Aripiprazole 30mg'],
  [],
  ['Abiraterone 250mg', 'Abiraterone 500mg']],
 'Manufacture_name': [['Manufactured by GlaxoSmithKline Inc.. '],
  ['Manufactured by VIIV Healthcare ULC. '],
  ['Manufactured by Otsuka Pharmaceuticals. ',
   'Manufactured by Bristol-Myers Squibb. ',
   'Manufactured by Otsuka Pharmaceuticals. ',
   'Manufactured by Otsuka Pharmaceuticals. ',
   'Manufactured by Bristol-Myers Squibb. ',
   'Manufactured by Otsuka Pharmaceuticals. ',
   'Manufactured by Otsuka Pharmaceuticals. ',
   'Manufactured by Otsuka Pharmaceuticals. '],
  ['Manufactured by Otsuka Pharmaceuticals. ',
   'Manufactured by Otsuka Pharmaceuticals. '],
  ['Manufactured by Janssen-Ortho. ', 'Manufactured by Janssen-Ortho. ']],
 'Manufacture_name_Generic': [['Manufactured by Apotex Inc. '],
  ['Manufactured by Mylan. '],
  ['Manufactured by Apotex Inc. ',
   'Manufactured by Apotex Inc. ',
   'Manufactured by Apotex Inc. ',
   'Manufactured by Apotex Inc. ',
   'Manufactured by Apotex Inc. ',
   'Manufactured by Pharmascience Inc.. '],
  [],
  ['Manufactured by Pharmascience Inc.. ',
   'Manufactured by Pharmascience Inc.. ']],
 'Product_Counry': [[' Product Of Canada'],
  [' Product Of Canada'],
  [' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada'],
  [' Product Of Canada', ' Product Of Canada'],
  [' Product Of Canada', ' Product Of Canada']],
 'Product_Country_Generic': [[' Product Of Canada'],
  [' Product Of Canada'],
  [' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada',
   ' Product Of Canada'],
  [],
  [' Product Of Canada', ' Product Of Canada']],
 'Prescription_Required': [['Prescription Required'],
  ['Prescription Required'],
  ['Prescription Required',
   'Prescription Required',
   'Prescription Required',
   'Prescription Required',
   'Prescription Required',
   'Prescription Required',
   'Prescription Required',
   'Prescription Required'],
  ['Prescription Required', 'Prescription Required'],
  ['Prescription Required', 'Prescription Required']],
 'Prescription_Required_Generic': [['Prescription Required.  '],
  ['Prescription Required.  '],
  ['Prescription Required.  ',
   'Prescription Required.  ',
   'Prescription Required.  ',
   'Prescription Required.  ',
   'Prescription Required.  ',
   'Prescription Required.  '],
  [],
  ['Prescription Required.  ', 'Prescription Required.  ']],
 'Product_Details': [[{'300mg', '60 tabs - $630.00 USD ($10.50 per tabs)'},
   {'120 tabs - $1250.00 USD ($10.42 per tabs)', '300mg'},
   {'180 tabs - $1860.00 USD ($10.33 per tabs)', '300mg'}],
  [{'30 tabs - $810.00 USD ($27.00 per tabs)', '600mg/300mg'},
   {'60 tabs - $1610.00 USD ($26.83 per tabs)', '600mg/300mg'},
   {'600mg/300mg', '90 tabs - $2388.00 USD ($26.53 per tabs)'}],
  [{'2mg', '30 tabs - $114.00 USD ($3.80 per tabs)'},
   {'2mg', '60 tabs - $220.00 USD ($3.67 per tabs)'},
   {'2mg', '90 tabs - $330.00 USD ($3.67 per tabs)'},
   {'30 tabs - $131.00 USD ($4.37 per tabs)', '5mg'},
   {'5mg', '60 tabs - $254.00 USD ($4.23 per tabs)'},
   {'5mg', '90 tabs - $369.00 USD ($4.10 per tabs)'},
   {'10mg', '30 tabs - $144.00 USD ($4.80 per tabs)'},
   {'10mg', '60 tabs - $280.00 USD ($4.67 per tabs)'},
   {'10mg', '90 tabs - $408.00 USD ($4.53 per tabs)'},
   {'15mg', '30 tabs - $150.00 USD ($5.00 per tabs)'},
   {'15mg', '60 tabs - $294.00 USD ($4.90 per tabs)'},
   {'15mg', '90 tabs - $429.00 USD ($4.77 per tabs)'},
   {'20mg', '30 tabs - $144.00 USD ($4.80 per tabs)'},
   {'20mg', '60 tabs - $284.00 USD ($4.73 per tabs)'},
   {'20mg', '90 tabs - $417.00 USD ($4.63 per tabs)'},
   {'30 tabs - $144.00 USD ($4.80 per tabs)', '30mg'},
   {'30mg', '60 tabs - $284.00 USD ($4.73 per tabs)'},
   {'30mg', '90 tabs - $420.00 USD ($4.67 per tabs)'},
   {'1 injection - $589.96 USD ($589.96 per injection)', '300mg'},
   {'2 injection - $1169.90 USD ($584.95 per injection)', '300mg'},
   {'3 injection - $1729.86 USD ($576.62 per injection)', '300mg'},
   {'1 injection - $559.36 USD ($559.36 per injection)', '400mg'},
   {'2 injection - $1108.70 USD ($554.35 per injection)', '400mg'},
   {'3 injection - $1638.06 USD ($546.02 per injection)', '400mg'}],
  [{'1 injection - $589.96 USD ($589.96 per injection)', '300mg'},
   {'2 injection - $1169.90 USD ($584.95 per injection)', '300mg'},
   {'3 injection - $1729.86 USD ($576.62 per injection)', '300mg'},
   {'1 injection - $559.36 USD ($559.36 per injection)', '400mg'},
   {'2 injection - $1108.70 USD ($554.35 per injection)', '400mg'},
   {'3 injection - $1638.06 USD ($546.02 per injection)', '400mg'}],
  [{'120 tabs - $3789.00 USD ($31.58 per tabs)', '250mg'},
   {'500mg', '60 tabs - $3999.99 USD ($66.67 per tabs)'},
   {'120 tabs - $7899.99 USD ($65.83 per tabs)', '500mg'}]],
 'Product_Details_Generic': [[{'300mg',
    '60 tabs - $274.00 USD ($4.57 per tabs)'},
   {'120 tabs - $538.00 USD ($4.48 per tabs)', '300mg'},
   {'180 tabs - $789.00 USD ($4.38 per tabs)', '300mg'}],
  [{'30 tabs - $200.00 USD ($6.67 per tabs)', '600mg/300mg'},
   {'60 tabs - $390.00 USD ($6.50 per tabs)', '600mg/300mg'},
   {'600mg/300mg', '90 tabs - $570.00 USD ($6.33 per tabs)'}],
  [{'2mg', '30 tabs - $35.00 USD ($1.17 per tabs)'},
   {'2mg', '60 tabs - $60.00 USD ($1.00 per tabs)'},
   {'2mg', '90 tabs - $78.00 USD ($0.87 per tabs)'},
   {'100 tabs - $80.00 USD ($0.80 per tabs)', '5mg'},
   {'100 tabs - $90.00 USD ($0.90 per tabs)', '10mg'},
   {'100 tabs - $99.00 USD ($0.99 per tabs)', '15mg'},
   {'100 tabs - $99.00 USD ($0.99 per tabs)', '20mg'},
   {'30 tabs - $45.00 USD ($1.50 per tabs)', '30mg'},
   {'30mg', '60 tabs - $80.00 USD ($1.33 per tabs)'},
   {'30mg', '90 tabs - $90.00 USD ($1.00 per tabs)'}],
  [],
  [{'120 tabs - $1690.00 USD ($14.08 per tabs)', '250mg'},
   {'240 tabs - $3370.00 USD ($14.04 per tabs)', '250mg'},
   {'250mg', '360 tabs - $4989.00 USD ($13.86 per tabs)'},
   {'500mg', '60 tabs - $1190.00 USD ($19.83 per tabs)'},
   {'120 tabs - $2290.00 USD ($19.08 per tabs)', '500mg'},
   {'180 tabs - $3390.00 USD ($18.83 per tabs)', '500mg'}]]}
```

Comment: Hello Laurent, I have added the requested post.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question again, Could you please check now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not a direct answer with question focus but instead of post-processing your `dataframe` I would recommend to change your scraping strategy and avoiding the bunch of `lists` may use a single one with more strucured data in `dicts`.

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://spfpharmacy.com/search/?drugName=A'
driver.get(url)
urls = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.drug_items a.rxrequired.default')]

data = []
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-type="brand"] option'):
        d = {
            'Medicine_name':e.get_attribute('data-brand-name'),
            'Manufacture_name':e.get_attribute('data-mfr'),
            'Product_Counry':e.get_attribute('data-country'),
            'Product_Qty':e.get_attribute('data-qty'),
            'Product_Unit_Price':e.get_attribute('data-unit-price'),
            'Product_Price':e.get_attribute('data-price'),
            'Prescription_Required':e.parent.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.product-prescription').text,
        }
        data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | Medicine_name | Manufacture_name | Product_Counry | Product_Qty | Product_Price | Prescription_Required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Ziagen | GlaxoSmithKline Inc. | Canada | 60 tabs | 630 | Prescription Required |
| 1 | Ziagen | GlaxoSmithKline Inc. | Canada | 120 tabs | 1250 | Prescription Required |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1496 | Azopt Eye Drops | Alcon | Canada | 10 ml | 80 | Prescription Required |
| 1497 | Azopt Eye Drops | Alcon | Canada | 15 ml | 97.5 | Prescription Required |

Comment: thanks this is what I am looking for. I also have another website with the same entries and will try to modify the code on that too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, but **watch out**, It will reshape your dataframe (5 rows, 11 columns) into a very large one (several millions of rows), which could make your computer unresponsive:

```py
# Deal with the last two columns (which contain lists of sets)
for col in ["Product_Details", "Product_Details_Generic"]:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: [subitem for item in x for subitem in item])

# Explode values of each column (except first one) into new rows
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df = df.explode(col, ignore_index=True)
```

With only the first two rows `df.loc[:1, :]`, here is what you get (71 rows):

```
            Medicine_Name   Bran_Name_Choices  \
0                Abacavir        Ziagen 300mg   
1                Abacavir        Ziagen 300mg   
2                Abacavir        Ziagen 300mg   
3                Abacavir        Ziagen 300mg   
4                Abacavir        Ziagen 300mg   
..                    ...                 ...   
67  Abacavir - Lamivudine  Kivexa 600mg/300mg   
68  Abacavir - Lamivudine  Kivexa 600mg/300mg   
69  Abacavir - Lamivudine  Kivexa 600mg/300mg   
70  Abacavir - Lamivudine  Kivexa 600mg/300mg   
71  Abacavir - Lamivudine  Kivexa 600mg/300mg   

                 Generic_Name_Choices                        Manufacture_name  \
0                      Abacavir 300mg  Manufactured by GlaxoSmithKline Inc..    
1                      Abacavir 300mg  Manufactured by GlaxoSmithKline Inc..    
2                      Abacavir 300mg  Manufactured by GlaxoSmithKline Inc..    
3                      Abacavir 300mg  Manufactured by GlaxoSmithKline Inc..    
4                      Abacavir 300mg  Manufactured by GlaxoSmithKline Inc..    
..                                ...                                     ...   
67  Abacavir - Lamivudine 600mg/300mg   Manufactured by VIIV Healthcare ULC.    
68  Abacavir - Lamivudine 600mg/300mg   Manufactured by VIIV Healthcare ULC.    
69  Abacavir - Lamivudine 600mg/300mg   Manufactured by VIIV Healthcare ULC.    
70  Abacavir - Lamivudine 600mg/300mg   Manufactured by VIIV Healthcare ULC.    
71  Abacavir - Lamivudine 600mg/300mg   Manufactured by VIIV Healthcare ULC.    

        Manufacture_name_Generic      Product_Counry Product_Country_Generic  \
0   Manufactured by Apotex Inc.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   
1   Manufactured by Apotex Inc.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   
2   Manufactured by Apotex Inc.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   
3   Manufactured by Apotex Inc.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   
4   Manufactured by Apotex Inc.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   
..                           ...                 ...                     ...   
67       Manufactured by Mylan.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   
68       Manufactured by Mylan.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   
69       Manufactured by Mylan.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   
70       Manufactured by Mylan.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   
71       Manufactured by Mylan.    Product Of Canada       Product Of Canada   

    Prescription_Required Prescription_Required_Generic  \
0   Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     
1   Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     
2   Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     
3   Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     
4   Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     
..                    ...                           ...   
67  Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     
68  Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     
69  Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     
70  Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     
71  Prescription Required      Prescription Required.     

                            Product_Details  \
0   60 tabs - $630.00 USD ($10.50 per tabs)   
1   60 tabs - $630.00 USD ($10.50 per tabs)   
2   60 tabs - $630.00 USD ($10.50 per tabs)   
3   60 tabs - $630.00 USD ($10.50 per tabs)   
4   60 tabs - $630.00 USD ($10.50 per tabs)   
..                                      ...   
67                              600mg/300mg   
68                              600mg/300mg   
69                              600mg/300mg   
70                              600mg/300mg   
71                              600mg/300mg   

                    Product_Details_Generic  
0    60 tabs - $274.00 USD ($4.57 per tabs)  
1                                     300mg  
2   120 tabs - $538.00 USD ($4.48 per tabs)  
3                                     300mg  
4   180 tabs - $789.00 USD ($4.38 per tabs)  
..                                      ...  
67                              600mg/300mg  
68   60 tabs - $390.00 USD ($6.50 per tabs)
69                              600mg/300mg
70   90 tabs - $570.00 USD ($6.33 per tabs)
71                              600mg/300mg

[72 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it's making the dataset with too many records.